# boost log, why not print threadid and processid

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I'm having trouble using the boost log library, as follows：

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(log_severity, "Severity", SeverityLevel)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(log_timestamp, "TimeStamp", boost::posix_time::ptime)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(log_uptime, "Uptime", attrs::timer::value_type)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(log_scope, "Scope", attrs::named_scope::value_type)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(line_id, "LineID", unsigned int)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(thread_id, "ThreadID", unsigned int)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(process_id, "ProcessID", unsigned int)

    auto file_sink=logging::add_file_log
        (
        keywords::file_name="%Y-%m-%d_%N.log",     
        keywords::rotation_size=100*1024*1024,       
        keywords::time_based_rotation=sinks::file::rotation_at_time_point(0,0,0)   
        );



    file_sink->set_filter(log_severity>= Log_Info);   

    file_sink->locked_backend()->scan_for_files();

    logging::formatter formatter = expr::stream << "[" << log_timestamp << "] [" << line_id << "] [" << log_scope << "] [" << log_severity << "] [" << thread_id << "] [" << process_id << "] " << expr::message;

    file_sink->set_formatter(formatter);

    file_sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(console_sink);
    logging::add_common_attributes();
```

My call to the mian function is as follows：

```
src::severity_logger<SeverityLevel>lg;
BOOST_LOG_FUNCTION();
BOOST_LOG_SEV(lg, Log_Info) << "====main";
```

output message:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to create custom attribute keywords `ThreadID`, `ProcessID` and `TimeStamp`. Just simply construct formatter with [common attributes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/add_common_attributes.html) as follows:

```
logging::formatter formatter = expr::stream << 
    "[" << log_timestamp << 
    "] [" << line_id << 
    "] [" << log_scope << 
    "] [" << log_severity <<
    "] [" << logging::expressions::attr<logging::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type>("ThreadID") << 
    "] [" << logging::expressions::attr<logging::attributes::current_process_id::value_type>("ProcessID") << 
    "] " << expr::message;
```

However as Andrey pointed out, if you still want to create custom keywords that already exist, you have to specify their types:

```
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(thread_id, "ThreadID", logging::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type)
BOOST_LOG_ATTRIBUTE_KEYWORD(process_id, "ProcessID", logging::attributes::current_process_id::value_type)
```

Working example is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9b5DUzmzxCugDYdP).

Comment: why not`t create custom attribute keywords thread_id and process_id, timestamp can create custom attribute keywords?

Comment: You can declare keywords. You only need to correctly specify the value type. The original code incorrectly used `unsigned int`, while it should have used `logging::attributes::current_thread_id::value_type` and `logging::attributes::current_process_id::value_type`.